# Servlets: sendRedirect is redirecting to incorrect url?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets

I run my app from Eclipse's Servers view. Currently urls that are shown to the user look like:

```
http://localhost:8082/EclipseProjectName/path
```

I haven't specified this EclipseProjectName anywhere in my files but it's present there.

Currently when I invoke `response.sendRedirect("/path")`, then user is redirected not to `http://localhost:8082/EclipseProjectName/path`, but to `http://localhost:8082/path`

How do I solve that problem?

Comment: http://localhost:8082/EclipseProjectName/path and http://localhost:8082/path same because sometimes response does not consider the root diectory.Can you explain a little bit more about your example because I am not thinking that this may cause a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect to `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/path");` But I don't know whether it's a correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try without the slash:

> response.sendRedirect("path");